# How do you put an XML value into an array in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I want to go through an XML document that has nodes with text in them and attributes with links to a file then sort and display them alphabetically.  This is just some code I made to try to figure out why it's not setting the key and variable:

```
foreach( $container as $value )
{
  $title = $value->nodeValue;
  $link = $value->getAttribute('links');
      
  $cashflowtoolarray[] = array( $title => $link );
}
foreach($cashflowtoolarray as $title=>$link)
{
echo "Key=" . $title . ", Value=" . $link;
echo "<br>";
}
```

What this outputs is:

> Key=0, Value=Array
>
> Key=1, Value=Array
>
> Key=2, Value=Array
>
> Key=3, Value=Array

I want it to output:

> Key= Some title 1 , Value=somelink1.pdf
>
> Key= Some title 2 , Value=somelink2.pdf
>
> Key= Some title 4 , Value=somelink4.pdf
>
> Key= Some title 3 , Value=somelink3.pdf

It seems like it's not setting the values at all, how to I get it to set them? I'm new to this stuff so I'm very confused, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do a `print_r()` on `$link`, see what that gives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) cast to string

```
$title = (string)$value->nodeValue;
$link = (string)$value->getAttribute('links');
```

(2) set associative array like this

```
$cashflowtoolarray[$title] = $link;
```

Be aware that associative array keys are unique, if `$title = "foo"` and `$cashflowtoolarray['foo']` is already set, it will overwrite this element.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works now.  But how would I sort this?  When I go to sort it it's saying: "sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given"

I'm trying to sort the $title alphabetically in the array.  Again thank you so much, I'm new to this. Right now I'm using: "sort($cashflowtoolsarray, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);"

Comment: @user3179363 Glad I could help. `ksort()` is your friend, look it up. Please consider accepting my answer, by clicking on the tick left of my answer!

Comment: Thanks again, I accepted your answer.  Didn't realize there was a ksort, thanks for you help.